# Laravel How can I save a 1:many relationship?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.3 and I am trying to save a 1:many relationship that is coming in from post data.

I have the relationships set up and they are working correctly when I read the objects, but I haven't figured out how to actually save them. (hard coding up to this point).

```
...
$data = new Student;
$data->fill($request->all());

$student = Student::find($request->id); // get the id of the newly created student

foreach ($request->activities as $activity) {
    $student->activities()->save([
        'student_id' => $request->id,
        'activity_id' => $activity,
    ]);
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 Call to a member function activities() on null
```

`activities` is coming across in my post data as an array.

```
activities[
    [0] => 1
    [0] => 2
     ...
]

The value(s) of each key are the id's of the activity.
```

**Activity**

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student');
}
```

**Student**

```
public function activities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Activity');
}
```

I am trying to save this relationship in a table called `activity_student`.

I think [this part from the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) is what I need, but I'm just not following along.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here is where I am struggling most to understand.

```
// Save things like first_name, last_name into students table
$student->fill($request->all()); 

if ($student->save()) {

    // grab the student's activities and insert into the activity_student table.
    // $activities is an array that only contains the id of the activity
      $student->activities()->sync($activities);
}
```

So I have an `activities` table, a `students` table, and a `activity_student` table. The models are above... I'm just going in circles at this point. :(

Thank you so much for your help!

**Solution**

Thank you so much @Jamal!

Here is what I ended up with.

```
...
if ($data->save()) {
    $student = Student::find($request->id);
    $student->activities()->attach($activities);
}

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error `Call to a member function activities() on null` when your object is null and in your case the student object is null. Place an if statement like:

Call to a member function activities() on null

```
$student = Student::find($request->id);
if($student){
foreach ($request->activities as $activity) {
    $student->activities()->save([
        'student_id' => $request->id,
        'activity_id' => $activity,
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I am just really struggling for some reason. I've looked into the `sync` method as well. I can't seem to wrap my head around saving a model into a pivot table. I've updated my question to hopefully better show my sticking point.

Comment: @Damon as you are doing many-to-many. follow this section https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: I didn't catch your comment - I'll look into that. Thank you!